# warning and deployment error

Tags: winforms, deployment, warnings, powerbuilder

when i am working in PB12 i am getting few warnings as"C0190: Instance variables of local structure type ('os_datasource') will be implicitly private in the next release". please help me to solve this.

I am also getting deployment error

```
---------- Deploy: Deploy of target console_ge_winform   (2:22:32 PM)
--------- Deploying project p_console_ge_winform
Checking project settings...
Project is being deployed to output path: D:\PB\PB12_MTS\console_ge_winform_WinformOutput
Generating .NET assembly file ...

Some functions/events/properties are not supported.
Deploy failed.
---------- Finished Deploy of target console_ge_winform   (2:23:25 PM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Local structures have been deprecated for the last few releases of PB, since PB8 if memory serves, but for sure since PB10. The solution is to create the structure as a global, e.g. click New, select PB Object tab, click Structure. Then remove the structure declaration from inside the object and use the global structure.

I'm not familiar with the second error but I would not be at all surprised if Winforms can't support local structures.

I should also mention that Sybase recommends using auto-instantiated User Objects instead of structures for most cases. See the PB help for details.